# Passport: session serialization failed with serialization functions present

Tags: serialization, passport.js, feathersjs

I'm adding authentication to node app using `feathers-passport with the following configuration:

```
.configure(feathersPassport({
    secret: 'some-secret',
    store: new MongoStore({db: 'demo-session'}),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}))
```

And I configure passport:

```
var localOptions = {
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
};

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  api.service('users').get(id, {}, done);
});

passport
    .use(new LocalStrategy(localOptions, function(email, password, done){
        api.service('users').authenticateLocal(email, password, done);
    }))
```

To authenticate, I have this route setup:

```
.post('/users/authenticate', function(request, response, next){
    passport.authenticate('local', function(error, user){
        //error comes back as null and user is a valid object
        request.login(user, function(error){
            if(error) return next(error);
            if(!user) return next(new Error("no user found"));
            else {
                var token = tokenIssue({id: user.id});
                response.status(201).json({token: token, id: user.id});
            }
        });
    })(request, response, next);
})
```

However, the session serialization always fails with the standard error: `Failed to serialize user into session`, which would normally indicate that the `serializeUser` and `deserializeUser` functions aren't present. Except in this case they are. I went through the passport source and here (line 265 of `authenticator.js`):

```
var stack = this._serializers;
(function pass(i, err, obj) {
// serializers use 'pass' as an error to skip processing
  if ('pass' === err) {
    err = undefined;
  }
  // an error or serialized object was obtained, done
  if (err || obj || obj === 0) { return done(err, obj); }

  var layer = stack[i];
  if (!layer) {
    return done(new Error('Failed to serialize user into session'));
  }
```

`this._serializers` prints out `[]` so when `var layer = stack[i]` is called, the check `if(!layer)` always passes and thus the error is thrown. It would seem like passport isn't picking up that I've defined the serialization functions and I'm unsure if that's a result of passport or a consequence of using `feathers-passport`. I followed the `feathers-passport` guide very closely and I can't figure out what exactly is going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.